# Is the normal force conservative?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, work, conservative-field

This question has already been asked before, but the answer to that question was the normal force is *not conservative* because it does *no work*.

However, a different user asked the question "is it possible for the normal force to do work," and one of the answers stated that *it could do work* in the instance of an elevator accelerating upwards.

So... can the normal force do work? And if the elevator example is in fact an example of the normal force doing work, is the normal force conservative?

Edit: I can see why many of you are marking this question as a duplicate (because the question titles are very similar), but please read again. As I explained, the answers to one of the questions I mentioned either were incorrect, did not take something into account, or my understanding of the concept is completely wrong. It would be much appreciated if someone could leave an answer.

Comment: I don't know if this is the question to which you referred, but then answers do indicate that work can be done by the normal force.

Comment: The answer indicates that the work the normal forces cancel each other out.

Comment: To cite the answer: "The normal force acting on the incline by the block does do work, but the normal force acting on the block by the incline does negative work, and the total work done by all normal forces in the system is zero... Therefore, the normal force can be considered a "constraint force", i.e. a force that does no work and is neither conservative nor non-conservative."